# How to know domain name from IP address in PHP

Tags: php, gethostbyaddr

As we know about PHP has an inbuilt function to get IP address of a domain name

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

**But is there any way to know domain name from Ip address?**

I have tried using [`gethostbyaddr`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) but it din't worked.

```
<?php echo gethostbyaddr( '198.252.206.16' ); ?>
```

I think there should be some way of using the command `dig` in combination with PHP in Linux but I am not sure.

Comment: What is your definition of "it didn't work"?

Comment: I am not sure, but look up for this function : `checkdnsrr();`

Comment: The same IP is used in an example in the manual (doesn't work because there are unicode characters in the domain name). In the same manual there are solutions via `exec` and using said `dig` command - so did you research this at all?

Comment: yes i did it i am trying to figure out from past couple of hours . tried everything to make it work but no success.

Comment: You can always use whois or try to use CURL and 'visit' that page and get info about it

Answer (score 1):

You can get the A adress of that server. If there are multiple websites on that webserver you do not get that information

Answer (score 0):

Try using a valid IP address. I tried going to the IP address that you provided, but nothing was there.

Comment: using stackoverflow ip now

Comment: Using the stackoverflow.com IP worked using `gethostbyaddr`, it returns the domain. I tried using the same code with my website but it returned something different. Is it working for you? or do u still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

> If you have shell access, Unix/Linux servers can use this for a
>   timeout response:
>
> shell_exec('host -W 2 0.0.0.0');
>
> Where 0.0.0.0 is of course the IP, and '2' is the number of seconds
>   for the timeout.  This returns a more detailed string of info, with
>   some additional text which might vary depending on the system, so if
>   you want a string with the hostname and nothing else, you'll have to
>   do some substring cutting.

Try this.